# DRF is not updating the database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here's the model:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# Create your models here.

def set_expiration():
    return datetime.today().date() + timedelta(days=30)


class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    expires_on = models.DateField(editable=False, default=set_expiration())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

And this is the view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def update_customer(request):
    try:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(email=request.data['email'])
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    serializer = CustomerSerializer(instance=customer, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And the serilizer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Customer


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

At this moment I have a record in database with `expires_on` set to `2022-03-14` and I want to update that to `2024-12-12` so I call the endpoint with the following data:

```
{
    "email": "myemail@mydomain.com",
    "expires_on": "2024-12-12"
}
```

The view returns this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "myemail@mydomain.com",
    "created_on": "2022-02-12",
    "expires_on": "2022-03-14"
}
```

This is the **existing** data. `expires_on` is **not** updated with the new value.

I get no error and no exception. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `editable=False` from expires_on field.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    expires_on = models.DateField(default=set_expiration())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```